# SQL dump to table like in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, phpmyadmin

I am developing a backup/restore app in yii. I need a mysql command to dump a table like phpmyadmin does, it does not wrap the foreign keys inside table definition, but put is as "ALTER TABLE" command.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `sales_detail`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales_detail` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `salesFk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productFk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(15,3) NOT NULL,
  `unitPrice` decimal(15,3) NOT NULL,
  `comUnitPrice` decimal(15,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `minUnitPrice` decimal(15,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `productFk` (`productFk`),
  KEY `salesFk` (`salesFk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=378 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `sales_detail`
--
ALTER TABLE `sales_detail`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sales_detail_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`productFk`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sales_detail_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`salesFk`) REFERENCES `sales` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: for simple single table dump you can use this command, mysqldump -u <db_username> -h <db_host> -p db_name table_name > table_name.sql

Comment: First... why? Why would you do it this way?  Second... why not read the source code from phpmyadmin?

Comment: Take a look at the database migration creator: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/gii-migration-generator/

Comment: I had to do this since many backup/restore extensions in yii will include the keys inside the table definitions while the order of table definitions could not be arranged (or to me it looks like order by name of the table). Therefore, the restore process could produce some errors. Good idea to read into the phpmyadmin source code.

Comment: use the mysql command 'SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename' for that.